# Linked objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I created application that looks like user profile, its local app, I can add photo, change status add friends, also I can find, add and delete users. All this is in one screen(it not app to appStore it my test project). So, I have I issue with implementing friend list. I want to add user2 to friends of user1 and then I change profile to user2 and see user1 in his friends. I can do it with NSMutableArray of something like this but my purpose to have that users linked to each other. So, then I delete one of this users, it user must be deleted from friends from other users. How can I do it?

My code:
class DataSource are responsible for managing data

```
- (BOOL)makeFriendshipUser1:(NSString *)name1 user2:(NSString *)name2

BOOL success = NO;

User *user1 = [self lookupUser:name1];
User *user2 = [self lookupUser:name2];

if (user1 && user2)
{
    success = YES;
    [user1.friendList addObject:user2.name];
    [user2.friendList addObject:user1.name];
}

return success;
}



  - (void)deleteUser:(User *)user
 {
if ([self haveUserWithName:user.name])
{
    [self.activeUsers removeObject:user];
    for (User *u in self.activeUsers)
    {
        for (NSString *s in u.friendList)
        {
            if ([s isEqualToString:user.name])
            {
                [u.friendList removeObject:s];
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

User .m

```
  @implementation User

- (NSMutableArray *)friendList
{
if (!_friendList)
    _friendList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
return _friendList;
}

- (NSString *)friends
{
NSMutableString *a = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *s in self.friendList)
     {
         [a appendString:s];
         [a appendString:@"\n"];
     }
return [a copy];;
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What code did you write? Show us your effort!

Comment: lodo, I updated my post, my solutions works fine but I look for something better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common approach is to use Core Data. See the *Relationships* section of [Deleting a Managed Object in the Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html). It describes how you can choose to propagate object deletion through relationships by specifying different rules.

Another approach is to use custom `NSObject` subclasses. If you create your own objects you can manage most relationships by properly setting properties to `weak` and `strong`. You can also specify custom deletion logic, typically by overriding a setter. You can use `NSCoding` to write these objects to disk.